Bayesian Bootstrap on grouped data
I have data from an experiment where users are grouped. I have to calculate the treatment difference between each group, multiply the effect by some constant unique to each group (e.g., a "value" metric), and then sum resulting products. Call this metric "M".
My instinct is to run a bootstrap, but the data are huge, on the order of millions. (You can think of each row as a user.) So my next instinct was to run a Bayesian Bootstrap. I'm following what I think is the usual route: generate Dirichlet weights that sum to one across the data, and the proceeding as usual.
However, my bootstrapped results for "M" are way smaller than "M" calculated on the entire data set. Orders of magnitude smaller. My guess is that the weighting is not working correctly.
Another thought I had was to calculate the treatment differences within each group over the entire data, and then bootstrap over this reduced dataset. But my sense is that is not correct.
Another thought is to generate weights within each block, as if each block were its own dataset.
Looking for any thoughts. Thank you!
